# php curl issue not updating

Tags: php

I have used curl to extract data as follows

`$ch = curl_init();`

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sitename.com");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookiefilename.txt');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host:http://sitename.com'));
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $output = json_decode($output);
 cache_set($tableid,$output,'cache',strtotime("midnight +1 day +1 hour"));
```

However i am not getting anything in the $output object.

Comment: Use `curl_error()` to see whether there are any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var_dump($output)
```

to see what the value is. You can also try

```
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
```

to see if curl will tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the output you receive from your `curl_exec($ch)` is not JSON, you'll get nothing out of `json-decode($output)`. Is it JSON that you are expecting?